# Recover an unknown geometric sequence from $s(n)=\frac{1-r^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{1-r}$

Tags: summation, geometric-series

The standard equation for the sum of a geometric series is
$\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$
where $sum = a + ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^n$

Given another similar function, $s(n)=\frac{1-r^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{1-r}$ is it possible to find/recover an unknown sequence such that
$s(n)=a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n}$
 meaning instead of doing $s(2)$ I am a able to manually add up the components like $a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2}$ to get $s(2)$?

What I have already tried to do is use a sum law which states that $a_{n}=s_{n}-s_{n-1}$ and then rearrange to figure out what $a_{n}$ is. However this does not seem to work for me in practice because $s(0)$ should equal $a_{0}$, meaning $s(0)-s(-1)=a_{0}=s(0)$ but this does not happen with that equation and they are unequal.

What I'm thinking is that my function $s$ might not actually represent the sum of a geometric series anymore, could this be the case? How might I go about figuring this out?

Comment: $$a + ar + ar^2 + \dots +ar^n = a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$ It only equals the expression you gave when $a = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The $s_n$ is supposed to be $s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_n$, and that expression is only defined for $n \ge 0$. The concept of $s_{-1}$ doesn't make sense in this context.

So there is no such value as $s_{-1}$. The formula
$$s_n = \dfrac{1-r^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{1-r}$$
only holds for $n \ge 0$. The formula $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$ only holds for $n\ge 1$, and for $a_0$ instead we just have $$a_0 = s_0$$

Comment: I've completely rewritten this. The original series I gave was in error, in that $$\sum _{i-0}^n (\sqrt r)^n = \frac {1-r^{(n-1)/2}}{1-\sqrt r} \ne \frac {1-r^{\frac n2-1}}{1-\sqrt r}$$ Rather than correcting it, though, I decided to address the error you were making in your approach.